# How to smoothly scroll to an element in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling

I want to smoothly scroll to an element without using jQuery – just pure javascript. I would like a generic function to be able to both scroll down and scroll up smoothly to a specific position in the document.

I know I can use the following in jQuery:

```
$('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $('#myelementid').offset().top
}, 500);
```

How would I do it with just javascript?

This is what I am trying to do:

```js
function scrollToHalf(){
  //what do I do?
}
function scrollToSection(){
 //What should I do here?
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="scrollToHalf()" value="Scroll To 50% of Page">
    <br>
    <input type="button" onClick="scrollToSection()" value="Scroll To Section1">
    <section style="margin-top: 1000px;" id="section1">
      This is a section
</section>
```

In jquery I would do it like so:

```css
html, body{
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onClick="scrollToHalf()" value="Scroll To 50% of Page">
<br>
<input type="button" onClick="scrollToSection()" value="Scroll To Section1">
<section style="margin-top: 1000px;" id="section1">
  This is a section
</section>
<script>
function scrollToHalf(){
  var height = $('body').height();
 $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: height/2
    }, 500);
}
function scrollToSection(){
 $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $('#section1').offset().top
    }, 500);
}
</script>
```

EDIT: I would also like to be able to smooth scroll to a certain position on the page

EDIT: CSS solutions are also welcome (although I would prefer javascript solutions)

Comment: `scrollIntoView` is a viable option for your case. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634459/scrollintoview-block-vs-inline) for a detailed explanation for its use.

Comment: Modern browsers also have a pure CSS solution to the first part of your question: `scroll-behavior: smooth;`. Your JavaScript solution could then function as a fallback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smooth scroll anchor links WITHOUT jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733076/smooth-scroll-anchor-links-without-jquery)

Answer (score 51):

To scroll to a certain position in an exact amount of time, [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) can be put to use, calculating the appropriate current position each time. [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) can be used to a similar effect when `requestAnimationFrame` is not supported.

```js
/*
   @param pos: the y-position to scroll to (in pixels)
   @param time: the exact amount of time the scrolling will take (in milliseconds)
*/
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}
```

Demo:

```js
/*
   @param time: the exact amount of time the scrolling will take (in milliseconds)
   @param pos: the y-position to scroll to (in pixels)
*/
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.querySelector('div').offsetTop, 300)">
Scroll To Div (300ms)
</button>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.querySelector('div').offsetTop, 200)">
Scroll To Div (200ms)
</button>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.querySelector('div').offsetTop, 100)">
Scroll To Div (100ms)
</button>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.querySelector('div').offsetTop, 50)">
Scroll To Div (50ms)
</button>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.querySelector('div').offsetTop, 1000)">
Scroll To Div (1000ms)
</button>
<div style="margin: 500px 0px;">
DIV<p/>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(0, 500)">
Back To Top
</button>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.body.scrollHeight)">
Scroll To Bottom
</button>
</div>
<div style="margin: 500px 0px;">
</div>
<button style="margin-top: 100px;" onClick="scrollToSmoothly(500, 3000)">
Scroll To y-position 500px (3000ms)
</button>
```

For more complex cases, the [SmoothScroll.js library](https://github.com/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll) can be used, which handles smooth scrolling both vertically and horizontally, scrolling inside other container elements, different easing behaviors, scrolling relatively from the current position, and more.

```js
var easings = document.getElementById("easings");
for(var key in smoothScroll.easing){
    if(smoothScroll.easing.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = key;
        easings.add(option);
    }
}
document.getElementById('to-bottom').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    smoothScroll({yPos: 'end', easing: easings.value, duration: 2000});
});
document.getElementById('to-top').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    smoothScroll({yPos: 'start', easing: easings.value, duration: 2000});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll@1.2.0/src/smoothscroll.min.js" integrity="sha384-UdJHYJK9eDBy7vML0TvJGlCpvrJhCuOPGTc7tHbA+jHEgCgjWpPbmMvmd/2bzdXU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Taken from one of the library examples -->
Easing: <select id="easings"></select>
<button id="to-bottom">Scroll To Bottom</button>
<br>
<button id="to-top" style="margin-top: 5000px;">Scroll To Top</button>
```

Alternatively, you can pass an options object to [`window.scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/scroll) which scrolls to a specific x and y position and [`window.scrollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/scrollBy) which scrolls a certain amount from the current position:

```
// Scroll to specific values
// scrollTo is the same
window.scroll({
  top: 2500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// Scroll certain amounts from current position 
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 100, // could be negative value
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Demo:

```html
<button onClick="scrollToDiv()">Scroll To Element</button>
<div style="margin: 500px 0px;">Div</div>
<script>
function scrollToDiv(){
var elem = document.querySelector("div");
window.scroll({
      top: elem.offsetTop, 
      left: 0, 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
});
}
</script>
```

If you only need to scroll to an element, not a specific position in the document, you can use [`Element.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) with `behavior` set to `smooth`.

```
document.getElementById("elemID").scrollIntoView({ 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Demo:

```html
<button onClick="scrollToDiv()">Scroll To Element</button>
<div id="myDiv" style="margin: 500px 0px;">Div</div>
<script>
function scrollToDiv(){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").scrollIntoView({ 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
   });
}
</script>
```

Modern browsers support the [`scroll-behavior` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior), which can be used to make scrolling in the document smooth (without the need for JavaScript).  Anchor tags can be used for this by giving the anchor tag a `href` of `#` plus the `id` of the element to scroll to). You can also set the `scroll-behavior` property for a specific container like a `div` to make its contents scroll smoothly.

Demo:

```css
html, body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
a, a:visited{
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<a href="#elem">Scroll To Element</a>
<div id="elem" style="margin: 500px 0px;">Div</div>
```

The CSS `scroll-behavior` property works with JavaScript as well when using `window.scrollTo`.

Demo:

```css
html, body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="scrollToDiv()">Scroll To Element</button>
<div style="margin: 500px 0px;">Div</div>
<script>
function scrollToDiv(){
  var elem = document.querySelector("div");
  window.scrollTo(0, elem.offsetTop);
}
</script>
```

To check if the `scroll-behavior` property is supported, you can check if it exists as a key in the style of the HTML element.

```js
var scrollBehaviorSupported = 'scroll-behavior' in document.documentElement.style;
console.log('scroll-behavior supported:', scrollBehaviorSupported);
```

Comment: Really nice answer ! Especially liked the scrollBy which I wasn't aware of :)

Comment: @Baldráni Thanks! Glad to help!

Comment: A very thorough answer!

Answer (score 7):

Consider using [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Comment: This doesn't work in the Safari browser with an object parameter, any alternative?

Comment: @SnowBases See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use this CSS property you switch scroll behavior to be smooth.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

This will also scroll smoothly default html navigation by hash `<a href="#about">` to `<section id="about">`, and no js required here.

If you want to add own logic to scrolling consider this example

- https://jsfiddle.net/arsenlol/Ls3f2ujq/54/

here I am scrolling not directly to a scroll target element but 90px higher consdering fixed header height.

TL;DR

```
document.querySelectorAll("nav a").forEach(function (a) {
        a.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          const hash = event.target.getAttribute("href");
          const scrollTarget = document.querySelector(hash);
          
          // Some additional logic
          const headerHeight = 90;
          window.scrollTo(0, scrollTarget.offsetTop - headerHeight);
        });
      });
```

Comment: SO MUCH deprecated info online for this question and here is the answer in 2022 with 0 votes. Thanks @Arseniy Shelestyuk

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment, [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) is a good option to consider – that gets greater and greater browser support – when you try to scroll to a specified element such as what you are apparently trying to do with your `scrollToSection` function.

To scroll to the middle of the page you can set the `scrollTop` property of the `body` and/or the `html` element to half the difference of the `scrollHeight` of the body and the `innerHeight` of the window. Couple the above calculation with [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and you are set.

Here's how you can incorporate the above suggestions in your code:

```js
function scrollToHalf(duration) {
  var
    heightDiff = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight,
    endValue = heightDiff / 2,
    start = null;
    
  /* Set a default for the duration, in case it's not given. */
  duration = duration || 300;
  
  /* Start the animation. */
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function step (now) {
    /* Normalise the start date and calculate the current progress. */
    start = !start ? now : start;
    var progress = now - start;
    
    /* Increment by a calculate step the value of the scroll top. */
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = endValue * progress / duration;
    document.body.scrollTop = endValue * progress / duration;
    
    /* Check whether the current progress is less than the given duration. */
    if (progress < duration) {
      /* Execute the function recursively. */
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
    else {
      /* Set the scroll top to the end value. */
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = endValue;
      document.body.scrollTop = endValue;
    }
  });
}

function scrollToSection(element) {
  /* Scroll until the button's next sibling comes into view. */
  element.nextElementSibling.scrollIntoView({block: "start", behavior: "smooth"});
}
```

```css
#section1 {
  margin: 1000px 0;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="scrollToHalf()" value="Scroll To 50% of Page">
<br>
<input type="button" onClick="scrollToSection(this)" value="Scroll To Section1">
<section id="section1">
  This is a section
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can literally scroll any node object you want, with a simple polyfill like this:

```
Node.prototype.scroll = window.scroll
```

it will give you same access to scroll objects, but with any DOM element, you can use it like:

```
document.querySelector('.scrollable-div').scroll({
  top: 500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers to this question already, but I thought I might share what I use.

The following allows you to smooth scroll to any position on the page, downwards or upwards, within a specified amount of time.  I'm not sure if it's compatible with every browser, but I'm pretty sure it is.  (Someone correct me if I'm wrong.)

**Important Edit**: Make sure you don't have `html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}` in your CSS. Otherwise, this won't work.

```js
function scrollToInTime(element, duration) {
  const endPoint = document.querySelector(element).offsetTop,
    distance = endPoint - window.pageYOffset,
    rate = (distance * 4) / duration, // px/4ms
    interval = setInterval(scrollIncrement, 4) //4ms is minimum interval for browser

  function scrollIncrement() {
    const yOffset = Math.ceil(window.pageYOffset)

    if (
      (yOffset >= endPoint && rate >= 0) ||
      (yOffset <= endPoint && rate <= 0)
    ) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    } else {
      //keep in mind that scrollBy doesn't work with decimal pixels < 1 like 0.4px, so
      //if duration is too big, function won't work. rate must end up being >= 1px
      window.scrollBy(0, rate)
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a codepen as an example: https://codepen.io/isaac-svi/pen/xxZgPZp?editors=0110