# Smooth scrolling when scrolling down a div using JavaScript, scrolling back up is janky and slow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple page where I am going to place a large form on the right side, and a navigation menu on the left allowing the user to jump to sections of the large form (this could also be used for large articles too - for now to mock the size I have added a large bottom padding with CSS). The right column has been styled to fit the height of the window using height: 100vh.

When clicking a link on the right and the section `offsetTop` is greater than its parent's `scrollTop` the scrolling is smooth. I use a JavaScript `setTimeout` and I set the timeout's interval using a loop... this is great! However should I want to scroll up, that being the section's offsetTop is less than its parent's `scrollTop` I get problems - it is janky, slow and doesn't really work... I have been looking at this for too long so if someone can help I'd be most appreciative. This is my JavaScript function

```
function scrollToAchor(where, event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var element = document.querySelector('.aims-form__form').querySelector('a[name="' + where + '"]');
  var to = element.offsetTop - 30;
  var from = document.querySelector('.aims-form__form').scrollTop
  let timeOut = 0;

  if(to >= from) {
    for(let i = from; i <= to; i+=5) {
      // this works and is great!!!
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector('.aims-form__form').scrollTop = i;
      }, i/2);
    }
  } else {

    for(let k = from; k >= to; k-=5) {
      // I need to set the timeout Interval so the animation is smooth but it is really slow
      // with the above setInterval above we are counting up... How do I get this smooth
      timeOut = timeOut + (to + 15) / 2;

      setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector('.aims-form__form').scrollTop = i;
      }, timeOut);
    }
  }
}
```

This shouldn't phase me but I can't get my head around it and now I have a mental block. To understand the scrolling function better here is the HTML, however to get a full picture (including the necessary CSS) here is a jsbin of the full thing https://jsbin.com/nidevaj/edit?html,css,js,output

```
  <div class="aims-form">
    <div class="aims-form__navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAchor('section1', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAchor('section2', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAchor('section3', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAchor('section4', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="aims-form__form">
      <section>
        <a name="section1"></a>
        Section 1 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
        <a name="section2"></a>
        Section 2 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
        <a name="section3"></a>
        Section 3 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
      <a name="section4"></a>
        Section 4 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aren't you using jQuery in your project?

Comment: No, no jQuery - just plain JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CSS property `scroll-behavior` to `smooth` (supported by most modern browsers) which removes the need for Javascript. Just give the anchor tags a `href` of `#` plus the `name` of the anchor tag to scroll to and allow the normal scrolling to occur, except much more smooth.

```css
section{
  margin: 500px 0px;
}
html, body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
 <div class="aims-form">
    <div class="aims-form__navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#section4">Section 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="aims-form__form">
      <section>
        <a name="section1"></a>
        Section 1 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
        <a name="section2"></a>
        Section 2 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
        <a name="section3"></a>
        Section 3 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
      <a name="section4"></a>
        Section 4 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use Javascript, you can use a `for` loop with `window.scrollTo` and `setTimeout` as well as `setInterval` for smooth scrolling. I have written a function for this. To scroll to an element, provide the element's `offsetTop` as the `pos` argument.

```
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
  if (isNaN(pos)) {
    throw "Position must be a number";
  }
  if (pos < 0) {
    throw "Position can not be negative";
  }
  var currentPos = window.scrollY || window.screenTop;
  if (currentPos < pos) {
    var t = 10;
    for (let i = currentPos; i <= pos; i += 10) {
      t += 10;
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, i);
      }, t / 2);
    }
  } else {
    time = time || 2;
    var i = currentPos;
    var x;
    x = setInterval(function() {
      window.scrollTo(0, i);
      i -= 10;
      if (i <= pos) {
        clearInterval(x);
      }
    }, time);
  }
}
```

```css
section{
  margin: 500px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aims-form">
    <div class="aims-form__navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAchor('section1', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAchor('section2', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAchor('section3', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAchor('section4', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="aims-form__form">
      <section>
        <a name="section1"></a>
        Section 1 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
        <a name="section2"></a>
        Section 2 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
        <a name="section3"></a>
        Section 3 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
      <a name="section4"></a>
        Section 4 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
        <button onClick="scrollToTop()">
        Back To Top
        </button>
      </section>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
  if (isNaN(pos)) {
    throw "Position must be a number";
  }
  if (pos < 0) {
    throw "Position can not be negative";
  }
  var currentPos = window.scrollY || window.screenTop;
  if (currentPos < pos) {
    var t = 10;
    for (let i = currentPos; i <= pos; i += 10) {
      t += 10;
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, i);
      }, t / 2);
    }
  } else {
    time = time || 2;
    var i = currentPos;
    var x;
    x = setInterval(function() {
      window.scrollTo(0, i);
      i -= 10;
      if (i <= pos) {
        clearInterval(x);
      }
    }, time);
  }
}
function scrollToAchor(where, event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var element = document.querySelector('.aims-form__form').querySelector('a[name="' + where + '"]');
  scrollToSmoothly(element.offsetTop); 
}
function scrollToTop(){
  scrollToSmoothly(0);
}
</script>
```

If you want to have the contents of a `div` scroll smoothly, you can use the above function, replacing `window.scrollTo` with `elem.scrollTop` and passing in the element's `offsetTop` as the `pos` to scroll to the element.

```css
section{
  margin: 500px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black; margin: auto; height: 250px; width: 50%; overflow-y: auto;" id="parent">
<div class="aims-form">
    <div class="aims-form__navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAnchor('section1', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAnchor('section2', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAnchor('section3', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onClick="scrollToAnchor('section4', event)" class="aims-form__anchor">Section 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="aims-form__form">
      <section>
        <a name="section1"></a>
        Section 1 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
        <a name="section2"></a>
        Section 2 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
        <a name="section3"></a>
        Section 3 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
      </section>
      <section>
      <a name="section4"></a>
        Section 4 
        <br>
        ... content lots of content
        <p/>
        <button onClick="scrollToTopOfDiv()">
        Back To Top
        </button>
      </section>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function scrollToSmoothlyInsideElement(elem, pos, time) {
  if (isNaN(pos)) {
    throw "Position must be a number";
  }
  if (pos < 0) {
    throw "Position can not be negative";
  }
  var currentPos = elem.scrollTop;
  if (currentPos < pos) {
    var t = 10;
    for (let i = currentPos; i <= pos; i += 10) {
      t += 10;
      setTimeout(function() {
       elem.scrollTop = i;
      }, t / 2);
    }
  } else {
    time = time || 2;
    var i = currentPos;
    var x;
    x = setInterval(function() {
      elem.scrollTop = i;
      i -= 10;
      if (i <= pos) {
        clearInterval(x);
      }
    }, time);
  }
}
function scrollToAnchor(where, event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  var element = document.querySelector('.aims-form__form').querySelector('a[name="' + where + '"]');
  var parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
  scrollToSmoothlyInsideElement(parent, element.offsetTop);
}
function scrollToTopOfDiv(){
  var elem = document.querySelector('#parent');
  scrollToSmoothlyInsideElement(elem, 0);
}
</script>
```

---

For a more comprehensive list of methods for smooth scrolling, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689657/9513184).

Comment: Thanks for the help, your input is great but as you can see from my example I am not scrolling via the window but rather a DIV I have with a set height and overflow set to scroll. I can't use anchors as it made my page "jump" as I need some of the the other content to be static (see the JsBin). So I am unsure if the function helps me, but I will try and adapt it for my problem.

Comment: @MikeSav As long as you know the dimensions of the `div` (you can also get them dynamically), you can use `window.scrollTo`.

Comment: Hi @Hev, I need the DIV to scroll to a position internally, see the DIV with the class "aims-form__form". This is static on the page as are other items (see https://output.jsbin.com/nidevaj) so I don't think window.scrollTo will help me here - thanks anyway

Comment: @MikeSav Have you tried putting `style="scroll-behavior: smooth;"` on the `div`?

Comment: @MikeSav I have edited my answer for a third solution.