# ReactJS - Scroll to a table's row as the page loads

Tags: reactjs

I've got a page with a table generated by a class component where, depending on some logic, I have only one of its rows "active" in a certain moment. I'm trying to scroll to the "active" row as the user opens the page.

I've already read this discussion but it didn't help
[ReactJS how to scroll to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/reactjs-how-to-scroll-to-an-element)

Doing like this I get that `this.scrollHere.current` is null

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.scrollHere = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
  // not using 'current', scrollIntoView() results not to be a function
  this.scrollHere.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'})
}

render() {
  return(
    ...
    <tr ref={this.scrollHere}><td>...</td></tr>
    ...
  )
}
```

Is that because the reference, when `componentDidMount()` is called, doesn't yet exist? If so, how to make it work?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689653/how-to-smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-in-pure-javascript and just take ref to element to make it working - it's all the same.

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this (use scrollIntoView), this issue with your code is that you are not using callback refs-:

it should be defined like this -:

```
    <tr ref={e => this.scrollHere = e}><td>....</td></tr>

    this.scrollHere.scrollIntoView()
```

Here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yzszzv

also replace 
`this.scrollHere.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'})`

with `this.scrollHere.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'})`

Comment: Yes, with the button it works, but I want to scroll automatically as the page renders on the browser, but if I write the code inside the `componentDidMount()` function I get that the reference is `NULL`, like it is not yet ready at that point, same if I give an id to the element and then use jQuery inside the lifecycle function, the element is `NULL`.
Can you build an example with the page which scrolls by itself as it shows up? Also if it shows up already scrolled would be fine.

Comment: Yeah sure check the link now... https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yzszzv

Comment: Does that help ??? Also you need to change `this.scrollHere.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'})`

with `this.scrollHere.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'})`