# scroll animation duration - javascript

Tags: javascript

I made an animation using scrollIntoView function. However the animation is very fast, I want to put a longer animation time, but I don't know how to do that.

That's what I put in relation to this function

```
section.scrollIntoView({
   behavior: 'smooth'
})
```

Explain to you what I did.

It is a page where the person will select an option. When she selects, the next section will appear with an animation and this scroll function also comes into action. Going to the new section that appeared.

Comment: I answered this a while back in a different thread.  Here's my answer.  Tell me if it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689653/how-to-smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-in-pure-javascript/62498602#62498602

Comment: Good to hear. 